# Folder mismatch after removing file extension .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.htaccess` file helping me to remove file extension from my pages, which i should say its working perfectly, but am having problems accessing site folders`(domain.com/folder_name/)` as am getting a 404 error with name of folder`(domain.com/folder_name.php)` having an extension in the error message. Below is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On    
RedirectMatch permanent ^/detail/((css|js)/.*)  /$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out; all i had to do was to create another .htaccess in the folder affected then add the following line of code:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

All is solved